# set text on textfield / textbox with the automation framework and get the change event

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, input, ui-automation

I want to set a text on a textfield / textbox element with the Mircosoft **UI Automation** framework, that means on a `AutomationElement` from the `ControlType.Edit` or `ControlType.Document`.

At the moment i'm using the `TextPattern` to get the text from one of these `AutomationElements`:

```
TextPattern tp = (TextPattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern);
string text = tp.DocumentRange.GetText(-1).Trim();
```

But now I want to set a new text in the `AutomationElement`. I can't find a method for this in the `TextPattern` class. So I'm trying to use the `ValuePattern` but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it:

```
ValuePattern value = element.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
value.SetValue(insertText);
```

Is there an other way to set the text value?

An other question is how can I get an event when the text was changed on a `Edit` / `Document` element? I tried to use the `TextChangedEvent` but i don't get any events fired when changing the text:

```
AutomationEventHandler ehTextChanged = new AutomationEventHandler(text_event);
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(TextPattern.TextChangedEvent, element, TreeScope.Element, ehTextChanged);

private void text_event(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text changed");
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the ValuePatern, it's the way to do it. From my own code :

```
ValuePattern etb = EditableTextBox.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
etb.SetValue("test");
```

You can register to `Event` using:

```
var myEventHandler= 
            new AutomationEventHandler(handler);

Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
    SelectionItemPattern.ElementSelectedEvent, // In your case you might want to use another pattern
    targetApp, 
    TreeScope.Descendants, 
    myEventHandler);
```

And the `handler` method:

```
private void handler(object src, AutomationEventArgs e) {...}
```

There is also an `AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler` (use `Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(...)` in this case) that can be useful.

Based on this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771275%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from MSDN.