# Microsoft UI Automation: ValuePattern not supported for RICHEDIT60W

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation, propertychanged

I'm developing an UI Automation application for Microsoft Word and I need to catch, for a RichEdit text box, the "AutoAddAutomationPropertyChanged" Event via a specific handler through method "AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler". I have my AutomationElement "element" that represents the RichEdit control and I added the event on my class:

```
Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, TreeScope.Subtree, OnPropertyChanged, new[] { ValuePattern.ValueProperty });
```

and my handler is:

```
 private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == ValuePattern.ValueProperty)
        {
            ...code...
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I execute this code on a RichEdit of type "RichEdit20W" it works and it catches the event, entering into OnPropertyChanged handler method. My problem is execute this code on a RICHED60W text control: it seems that the event is never triggered from Richedit60w text control so I cannot catch it to execute my handler code.

For example, with Microsoft Word 2010, if I execute this code using the RichEdit control of the window "Find&Replace", it works and the handler code is executed. Contrarily, if I execute the code using the RichEdit text control on the left of main Word application window, which is a RICHEDIT60W  ("Navigation" pane, opened with CTRL + F, and I used **Inspect.exe** tool to check it), it does not work and the handler code is never executed.
I'm very confused because if I try to catch the same property value changed event on RICHEDIT60W with **Accevent.exe** tool supplied by Windows SDK, the tool works properly and displays the event information.

I tried everything, even with TreeScope.Element and TreeScope.Children parameters on method, but nothing happens.

I follow this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.valuepattern.valueproperty(v=vs.110).aspx

to check if the element supports value pattern (obviously it supports...), and this:

[set text on textfield / textbox with the automation framework and get the change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720162/set-text-on-textfield-textbox-with-the-automation-framework-and-get-the-change)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.